# How to use "drag & drop" on websites?

Tags: browser, stock-browser, drag-n-drop

I use the adroid stock-browser and I'd like to play chess using e.g. http://www.shredderchess.de/schachproblem-des-tages.html Unfortunately you have to drag and drop the pawns. I tried several gestures, but I was not able to use the drag and drop feature. Do I have to change any options (where?) or should I use a different browser?

Comment: Most likely the best alternative is to download a chess app.

Answer (score 2):

Pair a Bluetooth mouse with your device. YouTube is full of demonstration videos such as [**this video** by Android Tech Tips](https://youtu.be/T1PCpXbf_kU).

Or use an OTG mouse, as demonstrated in [**this video** by XDA Developers](https://youtu.be/ciR50wDrLqI).

Answer (score 1):

Unless the website specifically supports touch screen, there's no way to do so. Unless the website uses a wrapper library like certain jquery plugins that can abstract the differences, the JavaScript code used to support mouse based drag and drop and touch screen drag and drop is quite different and incompatible with each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use puffin web browser and enable virtual mouse

Comment: Can you please link the browser app and mention how to enable virtual mouse? Thanks.